# Search for closed questions answered by a particular user

Tags: support, search

How can I search for closed questions that have been answered by a particular user?

Comment: Can we not search going to the concerned profile using the relevant tags?

Comment: @User1865345, what about including the condition that the question must be closed?

Comment: I have searched your [profile](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A53690+closed%3A1) for closed posts. Is this the solution? Perhaps not. But I am experimenting a bit.

Comment: @User1865345, this only finds my questions that have been closed. It does not find my answers to questions that have been closed. I am looking for the latter.

Comment: Hm. What I found is this Maths [post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20029/provide-a-way-to-search-for-a-users-answers-to-closed-questions#comment76008_20029) where they wrote a query for the same. You can check it. But as of whether a particular user's answer can be found out, I couldn't find any useful stuff so far. There is `closed:yes answers:1...` but this of course doesn't do the job.

Comment: Yes, that [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/edit/1712825) plausibly works.

Comment: One wrinkle is that *deleted* questions are only visible for users with at least 10,000 reputation. Under certain criteria, closed questions are automatically deleted, so this might be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

I found this script
[Answers to closed questions for user](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/1703865/answers-to-closed-questions-for-user)

But there is a line that prevents all results from showing up

```
questions.ClosedDate < answers.CreationDate
```

I edited it into [this script](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/1712823/answers-to-closed-questions-for-user?UserId=53690) and it seems to work.

Comment: This seems to work! Would it be possible to use the search window on Cross Validated to achieve that?

Comment: The search uses an inner join of two selections from the posts table. I don't believe that the search window is able to do that. It seems to only perform a single query of the type 'select ... from ... where ...'.

Answer (score 3):

https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A53690+is%3Aanswer+closed%3Ayes

[image]

For details, please consult the [search help page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

To find a user's identifying number, look them up on the [Users page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users).

Comment: Whuber, does it return the answers to the questions closed? It only returns the questions that were closed. After all, there are no "closed" answers.

Comment: @User1865345 As always, it links to them all.  If you want more flexibility, then use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

Comment: This only seems to return questions by user X that were closed. I am looking for answers by user X of questions that were closed.

Comment: Relevant Meta SO post: [Cannot search for answers on closed questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405697/cannot-search-for-answers-on-closed-questions).

Comment: That is indeed confusing.  Thank you for the clarification. The Meta post found by @User1865345 offers an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from Sextus Empiricus' [script](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6466/362671), the query provided at  Maths Meta [post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20029/provide-a-way-to-search-for-a-users-answers-to-closed-questions#comment76008_20029) also essentially caters to your requirements. Here is the link to the [script](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/edit/1712825): basically it orders the posts as per the scores.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work.